# Using Matchers.any() to match a mock object

Tags: java, tdd, mocking, mockito, matcher

```
Foo mockFoo1 = mock(Foo.class);
Foo mockFoo2 = mock(Foo.class);
when(((Foo) any()).someMethod()).thenReturn("Hello");
```

In the above sample code, line 3 fails with a NullPointerException. Why so?

My thought on this:

EITHER.. `any()` should be used for matching parameters rather than matching the objects on which methods are triggered.

OR .. `any()` works only for real concrete objects and not `mock` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do:

```
Foo mockFoo1 = mock(Foo.class);
Foo mockFoo2 = mock(Foo.class);
when(mockFoo1).someMethod().thenReturn("Hello");
when(mockFoo2).someMethod().thenReturn("Hello");
```

any() (shorter alias to anyObject()) is an Mockito argument matcher that matches any argument and only should be used as follows:

```
when(mockFoo1.someMethod(any())).thenReturn("Hello");
```

any() returns null, so your code was equivalent to

```
when(((Foo) null).someMethod()).thenReturn("Hello");
```

Comment: this answer seems to suffer from unmatched parentheses on the 3rd and 4th line. the difference from the perfect solution is only 2 characters, so i am unable to edit it. could you please correct it? thx!